# vuejs pdf from html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf

I need to generate pdf and paste the values of variables in certain places. In fact, this is going to be an order confirmation on my site. Later I will store it on firebase storage. which library do you recommend? Is there any way to generate pdf from html layout?

Comment: the library that you should use depends on your use case - and asking for library recommendations is considered off-topic

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are.

Python has : [xhtml2pdf](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-with-python-standalone) to convert html to pdf.

Otherwise, I would strongly recommend [reportlab](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) (still for python)

If you prefer to use Javascript there is [PDFKit](https://pdfkit.org/)